# TFS Builds target different referenced DLLs

Tags: msbuild

So I'm trying to setup builds for our different staging environments using TFS 2010 and msbuild. One of our staging environments uses a different version of a dll, lets call it "ThirdParty.dll".

So I want a build to target that environment, but this build will have the projects build against this older version of the "ThirdParty.dll". This dll is not in the gac, is not strongly signed, and no I can't change the enviroments to use the same dll.

So is there a way within TFS and msbuild to automate this? What do I need to look into to get started?

Answer (score 1):

You should be:

- storing the libs in source control
- using `Condition='<config=xx>'` on the `ItemGroup`s and/or properties within the MSBuild file to parameterise the location for the `Reference` as appropriate